# CSS Screen Resolution

Tags: css, resolution

I'm developing a website, to be more specific, this one: http://securitybreak.tk. The problem is that when I adjust my screen resolution, the webpage looks a lot different then in the resolution I've build it (1600x900). I tried many things, such as:

```
body{
width:100%;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include more code! What is the resolution it looks ok on? What browsers?

Comment: Can you post screenshots and code?

Comment: Please post some more specific examples of what doesn't work and what you have tried to fix it with.

Comment: I've tested it on IE10, Chrome and Firefox. This is a link to my style file: http://81.206.135.199/style/style.css, The things that I have tried so far: 1. Changing all the exact values to percentages 2. I've tried to include the code I've posted in the CSS file 3. I've tried using the @media function 4. I've tried working with absolute positions instead of relative, nothing really seems to work.

Comment: We will not be able to check if a website looks 'like you designed it'. Stackoverflow is meant to help you answer specific questions. People will be able to give you some 'pointers' on where to look, but this question, in its current state is too vague.

Comment: Good point, the page must fit on the screen without a scrollbar popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add width property to all elements that you want to scale. Don't add it to body, create a container. Then locate all divs inside it.

I'm adding code here to make it more comfortable to read:

```
<style>
    #container
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #left
    {
        width: 50%;
        background: #123456;
        float: left;
    }
    #right
    {
        width: 50%;
        background: #654321;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Notice that changing screen size also smoothly changes elements size.